# update value of a div with plus-minus buttons

Tags: jquery

I have this function :

```
    $("#inc<?php echo"$key"; ?>").click(function(){

    prod_id = "<?php echo"$key"; ?>";
    $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "updateproduct2cart.php",
    data: "itemid="+prod_id+"&act=update&qty=up"
    });

    var currentValue = $("#inc<?php echo"$key"; ?>").closest('#SCprodsB').next('#SCprodsF').find('#totalCommande').html();
    currentValue = parseFloat(currentValue);

    $(":text[name='qty<?php echo"$key"; ?>']").val(Number($(":text[name='qty<?php echo"$key"; ?>']").val()) + 1);

    var totalItems = parseFloat($("#qty<?php echo"$key"; ?>").val());
    var priceItem = parseFloat(<?php echo"$priceProduct"; ?>).toFixed(2);
    var totalValueUp = parseFloat(priceItem * totalItems).toFixed(2);
    $("#subtotal<?php echo"$key"; ?>").html("&#128; "+ totalValueUp);

    /* PART BELOW IS NOT WORKING PROPERLY*/

    var numItems = parseFloat($(":text[name='qty<?php echo"$key"; ?>']").val());
    var totalPriceItems = parseFloat(priceItem * numItems).toFixed(2);
    var newValue = parseFloat(currentValue + totalPriceItems).toFixed(2);
    $("#inc<?php echo"$key"; ?>").closest('#SCprodsB').next('#SCprodsF').find('#totalCommande').html(newValue);

    });
```

And this is the HTML part :

```
<table id="SCproduits" summary="commande">
    <caption></caption>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th scope="col">--</th>
            <th scope="col">--</th>
            <th scope="col">--</th>
            <th scope="col">--</th>
            <th scope="col">--</th>
            <th scope="col">--</th>
            <th scope="col">--</th>
            <th scope="col">--</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody id="SCprodsB">
        <tr id="prodItemi3" name="prodItemi3">
            <tr id="prodItemi4" name="prodItemi4">
                <th id="prodItemi4" scope="row">xxxxxxxxx</th>
                <td>xxx</td>
                <td>
                    <td>
                        <button id="deci4" class="SCbutton">-</button>
                        <input id="qtyi4" class="SCinput3" type="text" size="2" value="1"
                        name="qtyi4">
                        <button id="inci4" class="SCbutton">+</button>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <td>
                            <td>
                                <td>
            </tr>
    </tbody>
    <tfoot id="SCprodsF">
        <tr>
            <th scope="row"></th>
            <td colspan="7">€ <span id="totalCommande">xxx</span>

            </td>
        </tr>
    </tfoot>
</table>
```

I can't get the (span id="totalCommande") to be updated with the correct total value when using the (inci4 button). Any idea ? Am I going the wrong way ? Thanks

Comment: So what actually happens? Does it not update? Or does it not give you the value you expect?

Comment: it updates, but not the correct value

Comment: So...what do you expect and what do you get? What are the intermediate values?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem might be here:

```
var totalPriceItems = parseFloat(priceItem * numItems).toFixed(2);
var newValue = parseFloat(currentValue + totalPriceItems).toFixed(2);
```

By using `.toFixed` you are converting the number back to a string. Then when you add `currentValue` (a number) to `totalPriceItems` (a string), you end up doing string concatenation instead of addition.

So if `currentValue = 1` and `totalPriceItems = "2"`, you'll get `"12"` (a string) as you answer instead of `3`.

Comment: +1 you were right, didn't notice that, didn't even know that, and didn't find it in the doc :)
still, I don't get the right value, but I'll work this around, and let you know